# Using if loop in Field Calculator of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to calculate a field using Python with field calculator but am running into a syntax error. I'm hoping someone can point out what the error is, and I can't seem to figure it out. Below is the code.

Unfortunately, BUS_YR is stored as a string. It has the last 2 digits of a year and I'm trying to convert it into an integer of the full year. So 96 becomes 1996 and 00 becomes 2000.

```
def Reclass(NEWYEAR):
  BUS_YR=int(BUS_YR)
  If BUS_YR > 90:
    return BUS_YR+1900
  Else: 
    return BUS_YR+2000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` and `else` need to be lower case in Python

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the code should read with the suggested correction ([as mentioned previously](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255557/115)) with `if` and `else`, lower cased.

```
def Reclass(NEWYEAR):  
    BUS_YR=int(BUS_YR)  
    if BUS_YR > 90:  
        return BUS_YR+1900  
    else:   
        return BUS_YR+2000
```